# Jquery - after cloning a div how to get it by pre set id?

Tags: jquery

I'm creating div dynamically by cloning with some content. After this I have to change content dynamically. For example bellow div's are generating dynamically by `$.each` and set the content.

```
<div id="tab1">
 <div class="content">content 1</div>
</div>
<div id="tab2">
 <div class="content">content 2</div>
</div>
<div id="tab3">
 <div class="content">content 3</div>
</div>
<div id="tab4">
 <div class="content">content 4</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to change content dynamically again. Here is a prat of my example code.

```
 $.each( data, function( key, d ) {
   var $tabId = '#tab'+d.id;
   //check is ID created
   if(document.getElementById($tabId) == null)
   {
     $newTab = $modelTab.clone().prop('id', $tabId );
     $newTab.find('.content').text(d.content);  //this part is working
   }
   else
   {
     $($tabId).find('.content').text(d.content); //not working
   }
 });
```

That mean's I just clone a div once at a time with ID and next I will just update the specific content. Please give me a solution. What I have to do?

Comment: should'nt ``var $tabId = '#tab'd.id;`` be ``var $tabId = '#tab'+d.id;``

Comment: Seems to me it should actually be `var $tabId = $(d);`, and then the `if` condition should be `if($tabId == null)`. But it's hard to figure out with the limited code that was provided. @Rashed, would you please edit your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, please include details regarding the results you are currently getting ("not working" is rather unhelpful), and the results you would like to see instead.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I have done a mistake just here ` '#tab'+d.id ` but in my code `if ` portion is working well, creating clone with different id and content. The problem is when next time it enter into `else` portion it does not access those ID tab1, tab2 etc. as following code. I just want to use cloned div by ID from other part of code.